# Windows 7 - Size

Tags: windows-7, windows

I currently have Windows 7 Home Premium installed on my laptop, and I am looking to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional.  I am looking to install the full version of Windows 7 Professional - not an upgrade version.

Could somebody tell me how large Windows 7 Home Premium and Windows 7 Professional are/how much disk space they consume respectively?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I currently have the 64-bit version of Windows 7 Home Premium and that I wish to install/upgrade to Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my first Windows 7 Home Premium installation I used a 15GiB partition for the OS. This is definitely too small! I kept it working for a while, but it complained about the space regularly. My current `C:\Windows` folder is 27.5GiB - big for Windows 7 Professional.

So I would advise for at least 50GiB of disk space, especially if your User files will be on the same partition.

edit:

- I only used the 64-bit version.
- I'm not talking about a fresh clean installation here. You get by with 10-15GiB for a while, but as time goes by the system will take up more space.

Comment: No it wasn't. The difference comes from:
1st: the time the system is installed now, because it just grows over time 
2nd: the hard limitation of partition with a fixed size (since the system just couldn't grow it had to avoid some growth, delete unused files or force me to do so)

Comment: The size problem is from winsxs (windows side by side) and the number of programs installed. It is not unusual to have windows 7 report 10GB or more in the winsxs folder. I too, would not install windows on a partition smaller than 50gb (note that winsxs only LOOKS like it takes taht much space because of hard links, but it is still unavailable because explorer doesn't know the difference)

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft groups all Windows 7 versions together on their [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements) regarding minimum system requirements for Windows 7. The following is a quote about hard drive space requirements.

> 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) wiki page also agrees with [Microsoft's page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements).

Answer (score 1):

A clean install of 32 Bit Windows 7 Home Premium takes ~6.00GB<sup>*</sup>. This will increase rapidly with updates and pagefile expansions, so I would think a typical install of Windows 7 alone is around 20GB. Plus you add to that with documents, programms, temp data, and it all starts adding up.

A clean install of 32 Bit Windows 7 Home Premium takes ~6.02GB<sup>*</sup>.

64-Bit may make a slighty bigger difference.

<sup>*Clean install on a VirtualBox VM.</sup>